# 10th order NARMA Neural Net Training Data?

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to implement an echo state recurrent neural network based on a few papers and I am having trouble replicating their training data used in an example. Rather than type it all out, I've included an image of the training description, the paper's training data output.

[Training Setup/Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EedIq.jpg)

[Training Output, First 200 Iterations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf4ZG.jpg)

Unfortunately, I have been unable to get mine to match the example in the paper. My output consistently saturates to 1.0 by the 100th iteration.

**What I don't understand is how the output can oscillate when all the constants, inputs, and output of tanh() are all positive.** Eventually it HAS to saturate right? I just want to understand what I am missing in how the equation is implemented.

Comment: Note that $\tanh$ just mapping its argument (nonlinear terms in $d(i)$ you also have an input $u(n)$ and a disturbance $delta$) onto $d(n+1)$ it does not mean that it will saturate. It might saturate for appropriate $u(n)$ and disturbances $delta$.